# Looping Array with a variable as a property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is an list (array) of objects, objects contains some properties, I want to read the properties and bind it to cell of the table! the problem is I can't set the variable as a property of objects in array like 
**result[index].properties[iindex]**

```
 function btnSuccesCallBack(result) {
    var customergrid = document.getElementById("customergrid");
    GridBind(customergrid, result,["CustomerID", "CustomerName", "PhoneNumber", "ProjectName"] );

}

function GridBind(customergrid, result, properties) {
for (var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
    var headertr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var iindex = 0; iindex < properties.length; iindex++) {
        var headertd = document.createElement("td");
        headertd.innerHTML = '&nbsp' + result[index].properties[iindex] + '&nbsp';
        headertr.appendChild(headertd);
    }
    customergrid.appendChild(headertr);
}
```

}

GridBind() is library tool so Properties of different tables is not the same. so I need to find some way to looping any object property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also access a property by using `[]` notation instead of `.` notation. For example:

```
result[index][properties[iindex]]
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 0):

You should access the `object` like:

```
result[index][properties[iindex]]
```

and not with the `.` (dot) notation